# Read/Write files with UNC path - in c++

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, network-programming

I wrote a bit of code that reads/writes stuff...

I would like to add an option to read/write to UNC paths.

A bit of code:

```
if (boost::filesystem::exists (file_name))
{
  std::ifstream in_file(file_name.c_str(), std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);
  if(in_file.is_open())
  {
    in_file.read(...);
    in_file.close();
  }
}
```

If the network share I am trying to use has been used before, this works.

But if I try with a share from a computer that I have not seen before, I get error:

```
boost::filesystem::status: Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password: "\\xx\test.txt"
```

I'd like to avoid the exception, check the boost::filesystem::status for... what ? Looking in documentation, it seems that it can tell me if I have a regular file, or a directory... but **how can I check if I have the correct permissions** ?

Is there a way to actually send in the user name and password ?

Edit: found that I could call

```
Net Use \\yourUNC\path /user:uname password
```

also: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375187(v=vs.85).aspx

I think either of these would make the code platform dependent ?

Also, if I do log in every time - in a sequence of 10000 calls, this would result in serious slowing down ?

Is there any way to check if the user is logged in ?

Note: I am using boost 1.47 - mostly windows but I'd like to be platform independent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found that I can check rights was to try... catch surrounding a check for file exist call.

If the try fails, it means I don't have rights and can call system("Net Use...")

This way, I only have to log in once even if I read/write 10,000 files...

I don't like the fact that I have to use try... catch, if there is a better way, and I'll find it, I'll update - if anyone knows of a better way, please let me know.